# Strange behaviour with String reversal function

Tags: python, string, recursion, reverse

I am using recursion to reverse a string. I am able to reverse a string successfully using following code.

```
def rev(string):
    if len(string)==0:
        return string
    if len(string)==1:
        return string
    else:
        s=string

        string = s[-1]+rev(s[:-1])

    return string
```

But when i am replacing return with print it is printing only the first two characters of answer and then throwing an error saying

> "TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects"

Example. when give '**StackOverflow**' to function and returned a value it returns '**wolfrevOkcatS**' corrrectly
but when I am trying to print the answer in the function itself, it is only printing "**tS**" giving the error above.

Comment: Short answer: Don't try to print the result in your recursive function. Return the result and print it in the calling code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you did something like this:

```
def rev(string):
    if len(string)==0:
        print string
    if len(string)==1:
        print string
    else:
        s=string

        string = s[-1]+rev(s[:-1])

    print string
```

Let's get right to the problem.  Supposed the string you are trying to reverse is `abc`.  In the first call, you will hit the else clause and try to evaluate:

```
'c' + rev('ab')
```

The problem is now that your function has no return statements, `rev('ab')` returns None.   And python raises an error when you try to concatenate a string with None.

With the return statements.  rev('ab') returns 'ba' and the plus sign can be used to concatenate `'c'` with `'ba'`.

As an aside, if you are ever trying to solve this problem in production code, you should be using the built in tools.

```
reversed_str = myStr[::-1]
reversed_str_iterator = reversed(myStr)
```

Answer (score 1):

To reverse a `string/list` in `Python` use `list[::-1]`

**Demo**

```
>>> my_str = 'StackOverflow'
>>> my_str[::-1]
'wolfrevOkcatS'
```

Comment: While this is true, the OP seems to be trying to understand recursion, not solve the specific problem of reversing a string. You're also demonstrating terrible form here, naming a variable `str`, thereby shadowing the built-in `str` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

If you're replacing `return` with `print`, your function will not return anything. In Python, that is the same as returning `None`. This breaks your recursive step where you concatenate the last letter of the string with the return value of the recursive call. Instead, you should just let the recursive call do its own printing (just call it), after print the last letter in a separate statement:

```
else:
    print(s[-1], end="") # or print s[-1], (with the comma!) if you're on Python 2
    rev(s[:-1])
```

Note that you probably want your base cases to print a newline in this situation, since otherwise you won't get one at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't `return` from a function, then the function implicitly returns `None`. By replacing `return` with `print`, you break the recursive functionality; it recurses, but the values computed in the recursive calls are not returned and used. If you want to `print` intermediate results for your own edification, do so, but do so just *before* each `return` statement, not *in place of* the `return` statements.